# Smart pointer test in a while loop: use the comma operator?

Tags: c++, loops, smart-pointers, comma-operator

I recently saw code like this:

```
// 3rd Party API: (paraphrased)
void APIResetIterator(int ID); // reset iterator for call to next()
Mogrifier* APINext(int ID); // User must delete pointer returned

...

typedef std::unique_ptr<Mogrifier> MogPtr;

...

const it listID = 42;
APIResetIterator(listID);
MogPtr elem;
while (elem.reset(APINext(listID)), elem) {
  // use elem
}
```

Is this a good idea? Does it work?

---

I'll add the corresponding for loop for easy reference:

```
for (MogPtr elem(APINext(listID)); elem; elem.reset(APINext(listID));) {
  // use elem
}
```

... doesn't strike me as really optimal either ...

Comment: What's the point of using the `unique_ptr` if you're going to reset it every iteration?

Comment: Why not throw a trigraph or two in there to really scratch the heads of your co-workers =P. Honestly though, I wouldn't have a problem with it if I saw it, and yes, it will work.

Comment: @sftrabbit: probably because APINext() provides a newed Mogrifier

Comment: The for loop you provided in the edit is not correct - the condition has to be second, the increment/reset has to be third. Make the condition clearer by comparing explicitly with `nullptr` and its a perfectly readable for loop header imo.

Comment: What I meant with "not correct" in my comment: The way it is now, the for loop skips the first element, because `APINext` is called twice before the loop body is entered the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe we should write it as:

```
template<class SPT, typename P>
SPT& reset(SPT& smartPtr, P ptr) {
  smartPtr.reset(ptr);
  return smartPtr;
}

for (MogPtr elem; reset(elem, APINext(listID));) {
  // use elem
}
```

Comment: The reset is the iteration step, not the condition. So don't disguise it as such. Also, in a typical for loop you really initialize the iterator (in this case, the MogPtr). No fancy reset-template-thingy needed - see my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

As said in the other answers: This is technically ok and works as intended. But that you are questioning it actually shows that it's not a good idea, because it lacks readability.

This is sort of a disguised for-loop, similar to this one:

```
int i = -1;
while (++i, i<10) { something(i); }
```

In other words, you can just make it clearer by actually using a for loop:

```
for (MogPtr elem{APINext(listID)}; elem != nullptr; elem.reset(APINext(listID)))
{
  // use elem
}
```

Only thing is that you have to type `APINext` twice (shock!) which is probably the reason why someone had written it the way it is now.

Lesson learned: Readability outweighs laziness.

**Edit:** imo it's actually a good thing to type `APINext(listID)` twice, because it makes clear that the first time it's actually an initialization, the other times, it's reassignment.

**Edit2:** The `Iterator/Next()` combination may look a bit unusual in C++, since C++ standard library iterators work with operator overloading. In Java and other languages without operator overloading, this is the normal way to do things. If you want, you can write a simple C++ style forward iterator wrapping the API calls:

```
class MogrifierIterator {
  MogPtr ptr_;
  int listID_
public:
  MogrifierIterator() : ptr_(nullptr) {} //end-Iterator
  explicit MogrifierIterator(int listID) : ptr(nullptr), listID_(listID)  { 
    APIResetIterator(listID_); 
    ptr_.reset(APINext(listID_));
  }

  Mogrifier& operator*() { return *ptr_; }
  Mogrifier* operator->() { return ptr_.get(); }
  MogrifierIterator& operator++() { ptr_.reset(APINext(listID_)); return *this; }

  bool operator==(MogrifierIterator const& other)
  { return (ptr_==other.ptr_) && (ptr_ == nullptr || listID_ == other.listID_); }
};

//...
for (MogrifierIterator it(listID); it != Mogrifieriterator(); ++it)
{
  it->mogrify();
}
```

It's not complete, I have not tested it and it may contain errors, but you get the gist :)

Comment: Weeell --- I personally don't find that very compelling either :-)

Comment: added explicit comparison with `nullptr` to make the usual for loop header obvious: `(<initialize>; <condition>; <step>)`

Comment: @MartinBa it's a standard for-loop for iterators that don't rely on operator overloading. But I added a sketch for an mor "C++ish" iterator class ;)

Comment: Readability cuts both ways, though. It's "good" to type it twice to show that it's used in two different ways (initial and assignment), removing a (slight) cognitive load on the reader. And the comma operator is so rare in most code bases to be arguably a (slight) load in itself. It's "bad" to type it twice because it introduces a (slight) cognitive load on the reader to establish that yes, it is exactly the same both times it appears. I think this one can be argued pretty much however one prefers, simply by observing that the less-favoured option is (slightly) unreadable.

Comment: I get your point. However, in addition to the cognitive load aspect there is anothetr thing to (fluent) readability: familiarity. Skimming a code that contains an init-cond-step for loop es easy, because the eye is familiar with that scheme. One needs not necessarily notice the two appearances of `APINext` and wonder if they are the same. But the eye is not familiar with `while (A, B)` so even if we are not really interested in the loop and its condition, we stumble and stop to examine that curiosity, interrupting anythign we were actually up to.

Answer (score 1):

It should work. A bit tricky and not too obvious but otherwise does the job. Maybe using a for cycle would make the code clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Does it work? Well, it should, the syntax is valid: the pointer is reset to the value returned by `APINext()`, then it's tested for `NULL` in the `while` condition.

Is this a good idea? It's a matter of taste, but lots of people (including me) don't like that kind of code. It might be legal and working, but it is not that clear, takes a time to understand. For me, code **readability** very important and this particular code isn't good example of readability.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example of how to make it more readable while makeing sure that each element returned by next() is also free'd. I thought about it and found the corresponding for loop even more opaque ...

Answer (score 0):

It definitively works, but whether it is better than a for loop is another debate.  In this case, it avoids double code because getting the first element is the same as getting the next element (except for the `APIResetIterator(listID);`).  So this would be about idiomatic coding (for loop) or avoiding double code (getting first element and getting next element).

My advice would be to use iterators in a for loop, but this might be not that good in this case.