# Why does reset return void?

Tags: c++, reset, smart-pointers

All [`reset` functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) of `shared_ptr, auto_ptr, unique_ptr, boost::scoped_ptr` return `void` when they could really also return a reference to the object itself, because, if I reset a smart pointer to something, chances are, I'm going to use it. ([Maybe doubtful example.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15022085/321013))

That is, couldn't reset be defined as

```
unique_ptr& reset( pointer ptr = pointer() );
```

instead of

```
void reset( pointer ptr = pointer() );
```

?

Note: Essentially `reset`, which is really an "assignment" should just return `*this*` at the end, just like `operator=` already does. (It's not about returning the old value or somesuch.)

Comment: what's preventing you from writing a free function doing that?

Comment: Maybe whoever proposed unique_ptr thought its a good idea to encourage not to cram everything possible into a single line...

Comment: Seems a reasonable proposal to me, given that `operator=` is a similar operation and returns the same reference you're proposing. Unless there was a feeling in the committee that (despite already being rife in the C++ standard) chaining modifying operations is Inherently Bad, it's probably just a missed opportunity to do something that almost nobody will use, but mostly does no harm. Sometimes the reason something isn't in the standard is, "nobody proposed it", I'd be interested to know if this is one of those times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Boost` libraries go through a review process. The API is such as it is, because of that review. Your options are to either write an adapter class template or your own shared pointer class template. As `boost` code is often heavy, the latter option might not be a bad idea. You will then have complete control over the API.